# Excluding node_module when using include in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

I see a lot of people are excluding `node_modules` in thier `tsconfig.json`.
I am using `include` with specific folder patterns. Do I still need to exclude `node_modules`? How about third-party libraries that are not compiled into JS (i.e. included in my project as TS)?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "builds",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxFactory": "Vue",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "scripthost"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "types": ["jest", "node", "vuetify", "webpack-env"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "codes/**/*.ts",
    "codes/**/*.tsx",
    "shims/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for excluding `node_modules` is the independence of your compiler from the libraries as any package should be compiled to JS. If a package does not have the compiled version, I'd consider it unsafe.

Comment: Is not using `include` only enough to exclude `node_modules`?

Comment: Why do you say unsafe?

Comment: @geeko because if it's not compiled, the developer delegates the compilation to the users' of this library. But he mustn't. From there I can conclude that such a developer is not a professional and I cannot rely on the library he/she had written.

Comment: Thank you. How about my question in my 1st comment?

Comment: @geeko I am sorry didn't notice it. It's absolutely enough, you can just use `include`. The idea is having `node_modules` excluded from the compiler. It can be achieved either excluding node_modules or not including it to the `include: [...]`.

Comment: Thank you again. Why then I see that a lot of projects (like Vue CLI) are using both `include` and `exclude`? Is it to exclude referenced node modules from included modules?